# Handlebars, Javascript. При создании новой переменной с контентом все перестает работать

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars

Я использую Handlebars чтобы подгружить в HTML контент из Javascript файла. Вот так выглядит код, помещяющий текст в HTML div.

```
var mainInfo = "{{{header}}} {{{describtion}}}  {{{sentence3}}}";
var template = Handlebars.compile(mainInfo);
var data = template({
    header: "<h1>Powerful business</h1>", 
    describtion: '<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Donec turpis neque, sodales a faucibus at, viverra luctus urna. Suspendisse dignissim neque dui, in tincidunt arcu.</p>'
});

document.getElementById ("maintext").innerHTML += data;
```

Но когда я дублирую этот же код с другими именами переменных, для того чтобы так же подгрузить контент в длругие области веб-страницы, все перестает работать.

Опытным путем понял что создать новую переменную еще можно, но стоит присвоить ей handlebars выражение, например:

```
 var cerviceContent = "{{newheader}}} {{{content}}};
```

И текст исчезает отовсюду. Почему и как это исправить?

Comment: `var cerviceContent = "{{{newheader}}} {{{content}}}";` не парсится код из-за пропущенной открывающей фигурной скобки и закрывающей кавычки

Comment: @Igor Спасибо большое, стормозил. Если оформите как ответ, смогу отметить как верный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не парсится код из-за пропущенных открывающей фигурной скобки и закрывающей кавычки:

```
var cerviceContent = "{{{newheader}}} {{{content}}}";
```